# Parse json response of rest API and delete certain jsonObjects - JAVA

Tags: java, json

I have a json file as below which I am getting as a response from rest API:

```
{
  "label": " MARA LEYZIN",
  "ClassCode": "PROFESSIONAL",
  "actvFlg": "A",
  "name": "MARA LEYZIN",
  "Typ": {
    "label": "C_TYP_LU",
    "TypCode": "PROFESSIONAL  "
  },
  "Address": {
    "link": [],
    "firstRecord": 1,
    "pageSize": 10,
    "searchToken": "multi",
    "item": [
      {
        "label": "Address",
        "addrTypFk": {
          "label": "C_ADDRESS_TYPE_LU",
          "addrTypCd": "INDUSTRY",
          "addrTypDesc": "Industry"
        }
}
]
}
```

I am trying to parse this in Java and to remove some unwanted json objects. Like I want the following string to be replaced by blank:

```
"link": [],
    "firstRecord": 1,
    "pageSize": 10,
    "searchToken": "multi",
    "item":
```

To achieve this I am trying the following approach:

```
String jsonStr = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(inputFile)));
System.out.println(jsonStr);
jsonStr.replaceAll("link", "");
```

But it is not replacing the required string with blanks. Please help me in this.

Comment: You are not transforming it to a JSON object using JSON libraries. What you are currently doing is String replace which will end up with incorrect JSON(Note that String is immutable and you are just replacing.). To remove a JSON object, first parse it as JSON object and nullify the particular object or use `@JsonIgnore` or equivalent.

Comment: Strings are immutable. replaceAll produces new String you are not getting. Still it will not work as expected it will just leave "" instead of link. Why dont you just dont skip parsing this field instead of changing the response contents?

Answer (score 0):

string object is immutable , so basically if do you want to replace something
`System.out.println(jsonStr.replaceAll("link", ""));` this will print the replaced string but it will not affect the original string, however if you do this

```
jsonStr=jsonStr.replaceAll("link", "");
```

`System.out.println(jsonStr);` this will print the replaced string

Answer (score 0):

First of all:
Your JSON is not validate. You're missing a closing curly bracket at the end of it.

```
{
"label": " MARA LEYZIN",
"ClassCode": "PROFESSIONAL",
"actvFlg": "A",
"name": "MARA LEYZIN",
"Typ": {
    "label": "C_TYP_LU",
    "TypCode": "PROFESSIONAL  "
},
"Address": {
    "link": [],
    "firstRecord": 1,
    "pageSize": 10,
    "searchToken": "multi",
    "item": [{
        "label": "Address",
        "addrTypFk": {
            "label": "C_ADDRESS_TYPE_LU",
            "addrTypCd": "INDUSTRY",
            "addrTypDesc": "Industry"
        }
    }]
}
```

}

Second of all you should just change order of your commands to this:

```
jsonStr.replaceAll("link", "");
System.out.println(jsonStr);
```

**Important addition**:
And I would suggest you to use [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) library or even better JACKSON to parse JSON files.

[Here's tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/) how to use jackson and it's my warmest suggestion.
You will save a lot of time and you can do whatever you like.